# Finding the number of integers in the domain of a function given two conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We define a function $f(x)$ such that $f(14)=7$, and if there exists an integer $a$ such that $f(a)=b$, then $f(b)$ is defined and

$\bullet f(b)=3b+1$ if $b$ is odd

$\bullet f(b)=\frac{b}{2}$ if $b$ is even.

What is the smallest possible number of integers in the domain of $f$?

Here is my thought process: We have $f(14)=7,$ which we can find that $f(7)=22,$ and then $f(22)=11,$ etc. After completing these I got $15$ terms. However, there was a flaw. I then re-bashed this and got $\boxed{18}$ as my final answer. Is this right, or did I make a mistake.

Comment: I see, they are asking for the Collatz orbit containing 14, but they want you to count each number just once, even though it cycles 4,2,1,4,2,1 forever. Just write out really, really carefully.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same, so I suppose your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I got 18, check below

```
  1      14
  2       7
  3      22
  4      11
  5      34
  6      17
  7      52
  8      26
  9      13
 10      40
 11      20
 12      10
 13       5
 14      16
 15       8
 16       4
 17       2
 18       1
```